# Mach-o linker error after implementing playhaven

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, playhaven

After implementing the playhaven sdk, my app gives this error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I followed the instructions on how to implement, and I know I imported all the right frameworks. I have implemented this sdk in other apps before with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Facebook sdk I also had in my project had the same JSON files as the playhaven sdk, causing problems. Once I deleted the playhaven JSON folder, the app compiled and both sdks worked fine.